# Expo Locations.watchPositionAsync not being removed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation, gps, expo

I'm building a travel app. One of the screens in the app is a map screen. I use watchPositionAsync from Expo Locations. watchPositionAsync works great and passes the user coordinates. I want watchPositionAsync to stop/removed once the Map screen/Modal is closed. I append the .remove() function to watchPositionAsync, but unfortunately watchPositionAsync continues to run. How do I get it to stop running once the modal is closed?

I've tried using .remove() in various different ways:
- componentWillUnmount etc.
- I've even tried to execute it within a button (onPress)

```
async componentWillMount() {

    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);

    if (status === 'granted') {
      this._getLocationAsync();
    } else {
      this.setState({ error: 'Locations services needed' });
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      this._stopGetLocationAsync().catch(err => console.log('err'));
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
      const location = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
          {
              enableHighAccuracy: true,
              distanceInterval: 1,
              timeInterval: 10000
          },
          newLocation => {
              let coords = newLocation.coords;
          // this.props.getMyLocation sets my reducer state my_location
          this.props.getMyLocation({
              latitude: parseFloat(coords.latitude),
              longitude: parseFloat(coords.longitude)
          });
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
      return location;
  };

  _stopGetLocationAsync = async () => {
    const location = await Location.watchPositionAsync();
    return location.remove();
  };
```

I'm expecting watchPositionAsync to be removed after component unmounts but when I console.log(location.remove()) I'm getting undefined.

Answer (score 2):

In your `_stopGetLocationAsync`, you are creating a new `watchPositionAsync` promise object and removing it. Therefore the original one in `_getPositionASync` is still there.

You will need to change the const Location to a class variable, `i.e. this.location=...`, then pass the remove method to this variable.

here is the modified code

```
async componentWillMount() {

    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);

    if (status === 'granted') {
      this._getLocationAsync();
    } else {
      this.setState({ error: 'Locations services needed' });
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     this.location.remove(callback...);
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
      this.location = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
          {
              enableHighAccuracy: true,
              distanceInterval: 1,
              timeInterval: 10000
          },
          newLocation => {
              let coords = newLocation.coords;
          // this.props.getMyLocation sets my reducer state my_location
          this.props.getMyLocation({
              latitude: parseFloat(coords.latitude),
              longitude: parseFloat(coords.longitude)
          });
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
      return location;
  };
```